# How can I get environment variables in defaultConfig in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting `null` when using `System.env.FABRIC_API_ID`

[image]

I suspect I am doing something wrong regarding assigning values in a declarative way.

Here's my code

```
defaultConfig {

    ...

    def addConstant = {constantName, constantValue ->
        manifestPlaceholders = [ (constantName):constantValue]
        buildConfigField "String", "${constantName}", "\"${constantValue}\""
    }

    addConstant("FABRIC_API_ID",  System.env.FABRIC_API_ID) // System.env.FABRIC_API_ID is null here
}

//However it is not null when executing this task

task printEnv {
    println System.env.FABRIC_API_ID
}
```

How can I get env variable in this context? I am 100% sure that this variable is available as I can print it from a task using the same command.

Comment: Last I knew, environment variables are only available in Gradle build scripts when they are used outside of Android Studio. Android Studio does not pass environment variables into the Gradle daemon that it sets up.

Comment: It explains many questions of mine as interestingly it works fine when running from the gradle wrapper.

Comment: That has been the standard behavior. You might consider using `gradle.properties` or a separate properties file for this.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! Actually I have been doing this. The reason why I am trying to make it get from the environment is because my build is failing from travis. I don't want to commit my keys on the public repository and the only way that came to my mind to build my app from the CI was by doing so. Do have any suggestion?

Comment: Well, the CI isn't using Android Studio. So, use an environment variable, with a fallback to either a property defined in the run configuration, or a properties file that you don't commit to version control, or something. I don't do a lot of CI work, but there should be a standard pattern for this situation.